# Finding all matching elements in a list c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Bar bar {get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to find all object of Foo matching an Id in Bar in a list:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
int matchId = 1;
IEnumerable<Foo> fooMatches  = foos.FindAll(el => el.Bar.Id == matchId);
```

This just gives me a list with all elements in "foos", also them which not match an Id in Bar

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [findall in List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202183/findall-in-listt)

Comment: I'm assuming that in those lines of code you are skipping the bit where you populate `foos` for brevity. Because in the code you've shown you've got nothing in `foos`... Indeed it might help if you put in some sample data that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Your code is correct. Make sure all items in foos don't match your condition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> fooMatches = foos.Where(el => el.Bar.Id == matchId);
```

Comment: `Where` is basically the same as `FindAll`. I think that the way he's populating `foos` is somehow wrong.

Comment: You are right Tim: it's works now with Where() and FindAll(), the problem was somewhere else when "foos" were populated. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: @user1727107 your tag confused me because `FindAll` is not `LINQ` at all, it will generate a new List for you but not LINQ stuff, I've also not read it carefully.